# Recursive Function Name Error

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, error-handling

```
def a(j):

    lines=in_file.readlines()
    linex=[]
    for line in lines:
        line=line.strip("\n").split(" ")
        linex.append(line)
    print(linex)
    for i in linex:
        for j in i:
            if j=="":
                return 0
            elif j=="X" or j=="Y":
                return 0
            else:
                return a(j[:-1])

in_file=open("ncl.txt","r")
a(j)
```

Here is my code and I'm having a NameError with this code.

> NameError: name 'i' is not defined

So that I can't run the code.. Can you help me about it..

```
 linex = [['CATTCG', 'ACT'], ['GGTAC', 'GCATTA']] after file operations..
```

the small code that explains i what i'm trying to do :

```
def a(j):

   if j=="":
     return 0
   elif j=="X" or j=="Y":
     return 0
   else:
     return a(j[:-1])


a("GUGUUG")
```

I just want to generalize the code for every j in list.

Comment: Is `in_file` supposed to be the input?

Comment: when in_file i'm getting
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'readlines' .. in line 4 = lines=in_file.readlines() 
 and in line 17 =return a(i[:-1])

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: You need to define `i` in `a(i)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: read the code. that's not what he needs.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath,  yes it is they call the function with `a(i)` instead of `a(in_file)`, that is why they get a NameError  and he is a she

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Please, by all means feel free to confuse him (or her).

Comment: @İlaydaCansınKoç. change how you call the function to `a(in_file):` and the definition to `def a(in_file):`

Comment: @İlaydaCansınKoç, if you explain what the code is supposed to do it would help

Comment: first i read a file which has two columns and append them into a list as you see in linex(list of lists).. then i want to check whether the element in list that is in linex has "x" or "y" by recursive function i'm searcing for "x" 's and "y" 's.. so that my function call a(j) if it were a(in_file) it won't be sufficient for the code. @PadraicCunningham

Comment: @İlaydaCansınKoç, do you have to use recursion?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham unfortunately..

Comment: Not sure I totally follow your logic but this will apply your recursive function on each word http://pastebin.com/MWy6QJrL

Comment: i can't enter the site can you send it to my email? @PadraicCunningham

Comment: i managed to open :) thanx padraic

Comment: @İlaydaCansınKoç, no worries, like I said not totally sure of the logic but opening the file outside and passing in is definitely the way to go

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thank you so much Padraic:) by the way, is there a way splitting columns without using map?

Comment: @İlaydaCansınKoç. yep, just do it as you iterate, remove the map(... and do   `row = row.split()` after the `for row in f:`. You're welcome.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham hey padraic it's me again.. i was just wondering is there a way to appending return values to a list..

Comment: @İlaydaCansınKoç, hi, you can do it two ways http://pastebin.com/d2iJGKq1

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HG4Vrc0k  yes but i cant call the function in another function and print the out list.. o_O @PadraicCunningham

Comment: @İlaydaCansınKoç, are you saying you have to do it in the recursive function?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i managed to do it :D however i want to ask again, is there a way first spliiting rows in another function and then calling the splitting row process in another function for example in a

Comment: @İlaydaCansınKoç, yes http://pastebin.com/uBGFV8M0 just use it as `row = splt_row(line)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham hey padraic can i ask you a little bit confusing thing o_o

Answer (score -1):

The error is occuring because there is no variable named `j`.

Replace the `j` in `a(j)` with `in_file`.

Change this:

```
a(j)
```

To this:

```
a(in_file)
```

If you prefer to use `j` instead, then you would need to create/define the `j` variable like this:

```
j = open("ncl.txt", "r")
```

It is best practice to give a meaningful name to variables, exactly as you did with `in_file`.

Answer (score -1):

Then you post a code which uses some file, post a file too, really. Or at least add a content of that file in the code itself. You can do it by adding something like this at the beginning:

```
my_strings = """line 1
line 2
line 3"""
```

This is the same as doing this:

```
with open("somefile.txt","r") as my_file:
    my_string = my_file.read()
```

for a file containing this:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

About you doing readlines() in the body of that function, and then doing recursion. Get this outside, it doesn't belong there, and it will probably everything on the second call, because readlines() will return nothing if file is already has been read.

I'd recommend to use `for` loops instead of recursions, they are just safer and simplier. I didn't really understood what you are trying to do, so it's just a recommendation.

`lines` and `linex` are dangerous names, you'll mistake one for another one day and will search for a mistake for hours. Maybe call it like `all_lines` and `lines_list`?